# TouchDelegate to shrink ViewGroup touch area not working

Tags: android

I have a somewhat complicated layout. Some of the buttons on my layout have shadows on them, and I'm displaying those as images. The problem is that the images have a lot of extra space around them so they end up overlapping - when these images are being used in buttons that means the touch areas overlap.

After doing some reading and searching I've realised that the TouchDelegate class should be able to solve my problem perfectly, however I can't get it to work.

Based on the particular situation I have, I've created a small test project that is demonstrating the issue I am seeing. Below is the code from the various files comprising this test project, which reproduces the problem I am seeing:

activity_main.xml (layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/outer_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/inner_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:src="@drawable/button2_background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/button2_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/button_icon"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

button_icon.xml (drawable):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <corners android:radius="12.5dp"/>
            <size android:width="25dp" android:height="25dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <corners android:radius="12.5dp"/>
            <size android:width="25dp" android:height="25dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

button2_background.xml (drawable):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_purple"/>
            <size android:width="30dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="30dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.company.touchdelegatetest;

import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.TouchDelegate;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView button1;
    ConstraintLayout outerContainer;
    ConstraintLayout innerContainer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        outerContainer = findViewById(R.id.outer_container);
        innerContainer = findViewById(R.id.inner_container);

        button1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Button ONE Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });

        innerContainer.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Button TWO Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });

        outerContainer.post(() -> {
            Rect delegateArea = new Rect();
            innerContainer.getHitRect(delegateArea);
            DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            float leftOffsetDp = 30f;
            float leftOffsetPixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, leftOffsetDp, metrics);
            int pixels = Math.round(leftOffsetPixels);
            delegateArea.left += pixels;
            TouchDelegate touchDelegate = new TouchDelegate(delegateArea, innerContainer);
            outerContainer.setTouchDelegate(touchDelegate);
        });
    }
}
```

Image of what you should expect to see if you run the above:
[image: Image of project output]

There are two buttons in the centre left of the screen. Both are 150dp wide, however the rightmost one has an explicit margin of 120dp, meaning that its leftmost 30dp is on top of the first button. The small circle is for illustrative purposes only but is representative of what I have in my main application.

My expected behaviour:

- Clicking anywhere on the blue area will show a toast saying "Button ONE Clicked"
- Clicking anywhere on the red area with the green/white circle will show a toast saying "Button TWO Clicked"
- Clicking anywhere on the purple area (which is actually the left 30dp of button two) should show "Button ONE Clicked" due to the TouchDelegate that's been installed on the parent

Observed behaviour:

- Clicking on the blue/red areas as per expected, above
- Clicking the purple area shows "Button TWO Clicked" - the click has not been refused by the TouchDelegate.

Note that I'm running this on a device with API 22.

By using the debugger, I have confirmed that the Rectangle that's provided to the TouchDelegate object has expected values set.

Also by using the debugger, I have stepped through code in `dispatchTouchEvent` in `ViewGroup.java` and `View.java`, and observed that the touch delegate is only ever checked inside the `onTouchEvent()` function of `View.java`. In the situation I have illustrated below, the `onTouchEvent()` function of the View that the TouchDelegate is installed on is never called. This only gets called for the "inner_container" ConstraintLayout in my layout, but that's not the one that gets the TouchDelegate added, so it's never checked.

Making an anonymous override of the onTouchEvent method of TouchDelegate and putting a breakpoint in there also shows that it never gets run. The breakpoint never gets hit.

Am I misunderstanding how to use TouchDelegate here or is there some other way (preferably without having to create a custom subclass of View) that I can achieve what I want? (To re-iterate, the items will overlap but I want to cut off the touch area of button2 so the leftmost part of it that overlaps button1 doesn't register clicks on itself).

Also note that just moving the order of the two buttons around in the layout also doesn't solve my problem because then button1 will be overlapping button2.